# Non-linear fit in Python 2.7 doesn't give any good result

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

Here is my problem: I have experimental data to fit with a model. To do this, i used curve_fit from scipy. The script goes without any error or warning, but doesn't give a satisfying result (it gives me a quasi line instead of two Lorentzian shaped graph).

But the strangest part is that when I give a guessing array to the fitting function, none of the guessed parameters is modified, except for the third one (nevertheless it stay far from the expected value). However I pay attention to the order of the guessed parameters.

I give you the part of the code that does the fit.

```
X = 927.
Z = 88.
M = 5.e-15
O1 = 92975.
O2 = 93570.
bm = np.arctan2(Z,X)
P0 = 0.
T = np.pi/2.
TM = np.pi/3.
G = 20.

File ="Data.txt"
open(File,  "rb")
dat = np.loadtxt(File)

O = dat[:,1]

D = np.sqrt(1./20. *10**(dat[:,7]/10.)*1/((X**2+Z**2)*10**(6)))

def model(W,o1,o2,p0,t,tm,g):

    DB = np.abs((1./M)*(np.cos(bm-tm)*(p0*np.cos(t-tm)/(o1**2-W**2-1.j*g*W))+np.sin(bm-tm)*(p0*np.sin(t-tm)/((o2**2-W**2-1.j*g*W)))))

    return DB

guess = np.array([O1,O2,P0,T,TM,G])
fit , pcov = curve_fit(model, O , D , guess)
```

I search an research during a complete month to find any error, but still noting. Is It possible that the function is to complex for curve_fit?

Thank you in advance for your help. Don't hesitate if you need further informations or data

Here is a plot of `O` v `D`. The red points are the experiment and the blue line is the function with the returned fit parameters (not modified, so they are the guessing values)

[`D = model(O)`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBJSE.png)

[image]

Comment: Is it possible that here is no dependency on `o2` in your model function?

Comment: Could you please show us a plot of `O` vs `D`?

Comment: Your initial guess is probably not a good one since `model` evaluates to zero for all `W`

Comment: Check the value of `pcov`.  If it contains `nan` or `inf`, the fit did not succeed.

Comment: Hello
@gboffi : No, the dependency on `o2` is important, this is the parameter that give the position of one of the two peaks in the plot I haded.
@WarrenWeckesser : Yes, pcov is equal to inf so the fit does not work. I think i will try what M Newville proposed and see what `lmfit` gives me

Comment: I had indeed the suspect that `o2` was the position of one peak... I asked because in **your** `model` function THERE IS NO DEPENDENCY on `o2`. If you read the function, as you've posted it, THERE IS NO DEPENDENCY on `o2`

Comment: looking at the baselines of the theoretical Lorentzians vs the measured values, it seems that you have constant noise in the measurements, you should estimate the amplitude of the noise to get a better estimate of your curves.

Comment: maybe we don't use the same definition of dependency, but i actually see that `o2` is present in the formulae, in the last parenthesis.
And it's actually true, there is a background noise and i didn't take it in account at first, but it will be corrected, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it's very hard to tell what is going on with the mixture of constants and very long formulae.  But a couple points to consider:

1. If variables are not changing from their initial values, you should be careful about scaling.  Your (`X**2+Z**2)*10**(6)` will be around ~1e16, which might make it hard to make good numerical derivatives.  You may need to modify the value of `epsfcn` sent to `leastsq()`.
2. It looks like your model function calculates a complex array.  I believe curve_fit() can handle only strictly real values.

You might find the `lmfit` module useful.

Comment: Hello
First of all, thank you for your time and sorry for ll the variables, i really tried to make it simple to understand.
I don't really think this is a problem of complex array, since the function return the modulus of this array, so it is real. However, I will check this point.
But i didn't think about the scale of my values. I don't know (yet) what is `epsfcn`, I will look a this and the `lmfit` module.

Answer (score 0):

Well people, thank to you i finally found a solution!

instead of using `curve_fit`, i tried to use directly `leastsq` following [this tutorial](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html#least-square-fitting-leastsq) in order to see what would happend. It works better than expected since the fit did succeed and gives me the right positions of the peaks and there amplitudes. I give you the corrected code as it works for me.

```
X = 927.0
Z = 88.
M = 5.e-15
O1 = 92975.
O2 = 93570.
bm = np.arctan2(Z,X)
P0=1.e-12
T=np.pi/2.
TM=np.pi/3.
G=20.

File ="Data.csv"
open(File,  "rb")
dat = np.loadtxt(File)

O = dat[:,1]

D = np.sqrt(1/1000. *10**(dat[:,7]/10.)*50.*1/((X**2+Z**2)*10**(6)))

def resid(p, y, W) :
    o1,o2,p0,t,tm,g = p
    err=y-(np.abs((1./M)*(np.cos(bm-tm)*(p0*np.cos(t-tm)/(o1**2-W**2-1.j*g*W))+np.sin(bm-tm)*(p0*np.sin(t-tm)/((o2**2-W**2-1.j*g*W))))))
    return err

def peval(W,p) :
    return np.abs((1./M)*(np.cos(bm-p[4])*(p[2]*np.cos(p[3]-p[4])/(p[0]**2-W**2-1.j*p[5]*W))+np.sin(bm-p[4])*(p[2]*np.sin(p[3]-p[4])/((p[1]**2-W**2-1.j*p[5]*W)))))


guess = np.array([O1,O2,P0,T,TM,G])
plsq = leastsq(resid,guess,args=(D,O))
print plsq[0]

plt.yscale('log')
```

Again, thank you for your attention